# curl v/s file_get_contents performance for a file on same server

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

Currently I am using  `file_get_contents` to fetch files from cache (i.e files from same server and i don't need the different options that CURL provides.Will i get any performance benefits if I use `curl` instead of  `file_get_contents` for my case ?

```
$cachepath="/dev/shm/cache";
$cachedfile=$cachepath."/".sha1($this->URL['href']);
$content=file_get_contents($cachedfile);
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CURL you can expect worse performance.

Why?

Because it initiates a HTTP request, going through the network, invoking a response on the HTTP-server, starting some process (eg PHP), fetching the file, and then back to CURL.

If you use file_get_contents() you are only fetching the file, in the same process. It is bound to be faster than CURL.

Comment: you can't expect ANY performance from curl for local files. that's NOT what curl is for: curl can't even TRY to fetch a local file. f_g_c() would be just as slow as curl for fetching a url, because network/latency overhead will vastly outweigh any minor differences between curl and fgc when dealing with external resources.

Comment: @MarcB Theoretically you could use CURL to fetch the file from the same machine, if you make a script that serves the content of a requested file. It is of course a bad idea, because you are adding overhead that adds nothing functional.